# How to include Facebook feeds inside my page?

Tags: social-network

I want to include Facebook feeds from my Facebook page to my Drupal site as a block.
How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/) site and configure the kind of feed you would like to have. Save the generated the HTML somewhere.

Create a new block in your Drupal installation with the Full HTML text format. Paste the generated HTML in your the content part of your block.

If you do not want to use the default Facebook feed, take a look at [this drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/activitystream_facebook).

Comment: [Activity Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/deprecated) is deprecated, use [Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with [TB Social Feed](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_social_feed)